# GeoServer REST - Applying Style to Multiple layers

Tags: geoserver, rest, boundless-suite, curl

I have a bunch of rasters in GeoServer that need to have the same style applied to them as their default style. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the style of multiple layers as the same style. When publishing a layer make sure you select the same style for each layer in the default style drop down.